# The animation breaks between the transition

Tags: animation, three.js

I am building a 3d website using react and three.js. The animation breaks for a few seconds whenever I change the animation from one animation to another in my website. I don't know what the reason but this warning shows up **THREE.PropertyBinding: No target node found for track: Armature.quaternion.**

I am new to this so please tell me what to do ?

Here is my code:-

```
import { useAnimations, useFBX, useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";
import { useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { useControls } from "leva";
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";
import avatar from '../assets/3D/avatar.glb'
import typing from '../animations/Typing.fbx';
import standing from '../animations/Standing.fbx';
import falling from '../animations/Falling.fbx';

export function Avatar(props) {
  const { animation } = props;
  const { headFollow, cursorFollow, wireframe } = useControls({
    headFollow: false,
    cursorFollow: false,
    wireframe: false,
  });
  const avatarRef = useRef();
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF(avatar);

  const { animations: typingAnimation } = useFBX(typing);
  const { animations: standingAnimation } = useFBX(standing);
  const { animations: fallingAnimation } = useFBX(falling);

  typingAnimation[0].name = "Typing";
  standingAnimation[0].name = "Standing";
  fallingAnimation[0].name = "Falling";

  const { actions } = useAnimations(
    [typingAnimation[0], standingAnimation[0], fallingAnimation[0]],
    avatarRef
  );

  useFrame((state) => {
    if (headFollow) {
      avatarRef.current.getObjectByName("Head").lookAt(state.camera.position);
    }
    if (cursorFollow) {
      const target = new THREE.Vector3(state.mouse.x, state.mouse.y, 1);
      avatarRef.current.getObjectByName("Spine2").lookAt(target);
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    actions[animation].reset().fadeIn(0.5).play();
    return () => {
      actions[animation].reset().fadeOut(0.5);
    };
  }, [animation]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Object.values(materials).forEach((material) => {
      material.wireframe = wireframe;
    });
  }, [wireframe]);

  return (
    <group {...props} ref={avatarRef} dispose={null}>
      <group rotation-x={-Math.PI / 2}>
        <primitive object={nodes.Hips} />
        <skinnedMesh
          name="EyeLeft"
          geometry={nodes.EyeLeft.geometry}
          material={materials.Wolf3D_Eye}
          skeleton={nodes.EyeLeft.skeleton}
          morphTargetDictionary={nodes.EyeLeft.morphTargetDictionary}
          morphTargetInfluences={nodes.EyeLeft.morphTargetInfluences}
        />
        <skinnedMesh
          name="EyeRight"
          geometry={nodes.EyeRight.geometry}
          material={materials.Wolf3D_Eye}
          skeleton={nodes.EyeRight.skeleton}
          morphTargetDictionary={nodes.EyeRight.morphTargetDictionary}
          morphTargetInfluences={nodes.EyeRight.morphTargetInfluences}
        />
        <skinnedMesh
          name="Wolf3D_Head"
          geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Head.geometry}
          material={materials.Wolf3D_Skin}
          skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Head.skeleton}
          morphTargetDictionary={nodes.Wolf3D_Head.morphTargetDictionary}
          morphTargetInfluences={nodes.Wolf3D_Head.morphTargetInfluences}
        />
        <skinnedMesh
          name="Wolf3D_Teeth"
          geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Teeth.geometry}
          material={materials.Wolf3D_Teeth}
          skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Teeth.skeleton}
          morphTargetDictionary={nodes.Wolf3D_Teeth.morphTargetDictionary}
          morphTargetInfluences={nodes.Wolf3D_Teeth.morphTargetInfluences}
        />
        <skinnedMesh
          geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Hair.geometry}
          material={materials.Wolf3D_Hair}
          skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Hair.skeleton}
        />
        <skinnedMesh
          geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Glasses.geometry}
          material={materials.Wolf3D_Glasses}
          skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Glasses.skeleton}
        />
        <skinnedMesh
          name="Wolf3D_Outfit_Top"
          geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Top.geometry}
          material={materials.Wolf3D_Outfit_Top}
          skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Top.skeleton}
          morphTargetDictionary={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Top.morphTargetDictionary}
          morphTargetInfluences={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Top.morphTargetInfluences}
        />
        <skinnedMesh
          name="Wolf3D_Outfit_Bottom"
          geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Bottom.geometry}
          material={materials.Wolf3D_Outfit_Bottom}
          skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Bottom.skeleton}
          morphTargetDictionary={
            nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Bottom.morphTargetDictionary
          }
          morphTargetInfluences={
            nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Bottom.morphTargetInfluences
          }
        />
        <skinnedMesh
          name="Wolf3D_Outfit_Footwear"
          geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Footwear.geometry}
          material={materials.Wolf3D_Outfit_Footwear}
          skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Footwear.skeleton}
          morphTargetDictionary={
            nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Footwear.morphTargetDictionary
          }
          morphTargetInfluences={
            nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Footwear.morphTargetInfluences
          }
        />
        <skinnedMesh
          name="Wolf3D_Body"
          geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Body.geometry}
          material={materials.Wolf3D_Body}
          skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Body.skeleton}
          morphTargetDictionary={nodes.Wolf3D_Body.morphTargetDictionary}
          morphTargetInfluences={nodes.Wolf3D_Body.morphTargetInfluences}
        />
      </group>
    </group>
  );
}
```

I was going for the smooth transition between the animations using fadIn fadeOut but it is not working as expected

[Here is the link for the model and the animations](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1blyo8jSwUoCND7yVeuewj1Jqvf9Xhnxs?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you provide `model`?

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Mastalerz I have provided the model as well the animations in the google drive link.